# CSS HTML Class Not Working

Tags: html, css

for class I was given an HTML file and CSS file to edit. The code contains 2 tables and I am supposed style the one shown below. To do this I made a class called "mytable"

```
<table class=“mytable”>
<caption>My important data</caption>
<tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
<tr><td>1,1</td><td>1,2 okay</td></tr>
<tr><td>2,1 real wide</td><td>2,2</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>works?</td></tr>
<tr><td>another test</td><td>still work?</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is how I declared the class in my css file. It does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
.mytable tr { font-style: italic;}
.mytable td { background-color: green; text-align: center; width: 30% }
```

Comment: Fix the quotes you're using in `class=“mytable”`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working pen solution of your problem [here](https://codepen.io/himanshu9419/pen/rYJBLV)

change your quotes to  " " or ' ' as quotes you are using are not valid in html.

Will suggest to change your editor I thing you are using word. Use notepad or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

```
<table class="mytable">
<caption>My important data</caption>
<tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
<tr><td>1,1</td><td>1,2 okay</td></tr>
<tr><td>2,1 real wide</td><td>2,2</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>works?</td></tr>
<tr><td>another test</td><td>still work?</td></tr>
</table>



.mytable tr { font-style: italic;}
.mytable td { background-color: green; text-align: center; width: 30% }
```

Comment: You didn't explain what the actual issue was, and you merely changed the quotes as I noted in my comment earlier.

Comment: Please read the comments placeholder j08391 and see that is says to avoid answering questions in the comments. you are miss using stack overflow.

Comment: I explained a actual reason that has to do with editor he is using. Why is his quotes different from quotes that html accepts. Anyways I'm not bothered about you people down voting without reason or writing unnecessary things. I know people with sense won't follow you.

Comment: @Harry The entire question is based on a typo. Typo questions don't help anyone and are off-topic, which is why there's an explicit reason to close questions where the root is a typo. When you see such a question you should be voting to close it as such, not lecturing me on what to do. Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as a bad question when you are learning. People are at different stages. This is a good question because it is a specific question about a problem that the person was encountering while coding. Please read the guide lines on asking questions.